# How do I change this python line to let it read images of it's latest timestamp without stating a specific image name?

Tags: python, image, opencv, timestamp

```
img = cv2.imread('wayne.jpg')
```

This is my code, reading this image for openCV python, how do I change it so that the system will automatically select the latest photo uploaded to read instead of having to state a specific image ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to refine your question and show your effort attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use os module to list all image files in the folder and pick the latest one.

```
folder = '/example/folder/path'
files = [os.path.join(folder, f) for f in os.listdir(folder)]
filter(lambda x:x.endswith('.jpg'), files) # check if file is .jpg extension
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
latest_file = files[-1]
```

Then you can

```
img = cv2.imread(latest_file)
```